# AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'put'

Tags: google-app-engine, object, put

The following code:

```
class Message(db.Model):
    content = db.StringProperty()


class Message(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        doRender(self,'message.htm')

    def post(self):

        message = Message()
        message.content = self.request.get('content')
        message.put();
        self.redirect('/view')
```

gives me the error message below:

```
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'put'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What about the error message confuses you?

Answer (score 5):

That's not how you do it.

You `.put` on a model, not the `Message` class. You need to make a model using db or ndb first.

For your  example:

```
class Greeting(ndb.Model):
  content = ndb.StringProperty()
  date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

def post(self):

    message = Greeting()
    message.content = self.request.get('content')
    message.put();

    self.redirect('/view')
```

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/overview#storing

Comment: Paul O.k that make the think very clear to me - thanks for helping me Greatings Hendrikus

Comment: Paul do you mean that i can accept it as a answer to answer "Was this post useful to you?" ?

Comment: that's right. When you accept answers it encourages others to also answer your questions. It's how the site works :)

Comment: Paul I accepted it. Thanks for helping me >>> greetings Hendrikus

Comment: @HendrikusGodvliet: See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) you need to check the 'V' next to a post. It helps future visitors, you award the answerer, and you get some reputation too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the fact that you had two classes named "Message".  Pick unique names.